# automatic graphs

Tags: loops, graph, foreach, stata

I have a database in Stata by `country` and the regions these belong to. I want to create graphs with one variable (`varA`) by `year` for each `region`. In each graph I want the line of `varA` of every `country` belonging to that `region`.

I want to do it automatically because there are a lot of countries (however only five regions).
Any help to do this?

The database is like this:
region  varA
country 1 year 1     1
country 1 year 2     1
country 2 year 1     2
country 2 year 2     2
country 3 year 1     2
country 3 year 2     3

I tried using `foreach` command to loop the creation of the graphs but I can not figure out how to put in each `region` graph all the `varA` line series of each country in the region.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your code but I don't see that you need a loop here. The essence of what you want may be a line graph using `by()` to specify different regions.

This is an example you can run in your Stata. Some of the details won't necessarily apply to your dataset. `company` corresponds to `country` and `group` to `region` and `invest` to `varA`.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear 
gen group = mod(company, 2)  
xtset company year 
line invest year, c(L) by(group, imargin(medsmall) note("")) ysc(log) yla(1 10 100 1000, ang(h)) xtitle("")
```

Comment: You are a legend Nick!